# Which of the following three ways is the most efficient when constructing one MPI communicator?

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

When constructing a MPI communicator, we have the three ways:

```
int MPI_Comm_create(MPI_Comm comm, MPI_Group group, MPI_Comm *newcomm);
int MPI_Comm_create_group(MPI_Comm comm, MPI_Group group, int tag, MPI_Comm *newcomm);
int MPI_Comm_split(MPI_Comm comm, int color, int key, MPI_Comm *newcomm);
```

So which one is the most efficient way?

Comment: They are are used in different use cases. This is not about efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated by Zulan, these are different subroutines with different semantics.

From a performance point of view, i would not expect much difference between `MPI_Comm_create()` and `MPI_Comm_split()`

`MPI_Comm_create_group()` is a bit different, from the man page :

> MPI_Comm_create_group is similar to MPI_Comm_create; however,
>   MPI_Comm_create must be called by **all processes in** the group of **comm**,
>   whereas MPI_Comm_create_group must be called by **all processes in
>   group**, which is a subgroup of the group of comm.

From a performance point of view, that means there is room for optimization if only a small portion of the MPI tasks in `comm` will end up in a legit communicator.

Note this is just an observation based on the definitions, i did not run any benchmark on any MPI library, so there might not be any performance benefit in your environment.